# Sanitize latex commands and special symbol together

Tags: r, latex, xtable

We want to process many paragraphs of text from R automatically into LaTex. Those paragraphs originally are stored in entries in an excel file.

We read it and want to port each entry into LaTex. But in those paragraphs, we have special symbols like `&`, and we also want to include `\cite{}` as well.

My question is how I can output the latex file correctly with those symbols and commands?

In our paragraph, we have something like `"S&P 500"`, if I used

```
sanitize("S&P 500")
```

using xtable package in R, it will come out correctly. But what if I have `\cite{this-figure}` in the text as well.

Now if use

```
sanitize("\cite{this-figure")
```

It will not work and shows the warning:

> Error: '\c' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\c"

I understand why it did not work, if want the tex file to show `"\cite{this-figure}"`, correctly, the plain text show be double-backslash, `"\\cite{this-figure}"`

But of course, if I put this in

```
sanitize("\cite{this-figure}")
```

it will simply translate it 'honestly':

```
"$\\backslash$cite\\{this-figure\\}"
```

In a paragraph containing `"S&P 500"` and `"\cite{this-figure}"`, I will really want `"S&P 500"` come out as `"S\&P 500"` and `"\cite{this-figure}"` as `"\cite{this-figure}"`.

Many thanks

Comment: Sorry the double backslash version should be \\cite{this-figure}

Answer (score 1):

You could save the source text in a file, and then convert with [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/). For example, from R:

```r
file <- tempfile()

cat("S&P 500 \\cite{this-figure}", file = file)
tex <- knitr::pandoc(file, "latex", ext = "tex")

cat(readLines(tex))
#> S\&P 500 \cite{this-figure}
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>